# In NuxtJS, where do you insert the custom component-cache getter/setter?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Trying to implement my custom get / set for SSR compoment level cache. Docs point to [vuejs website](https://ssr.vuejs.org/api/#cache).

But, where is the `createRenderer` function called in NuxtJS or where do I implement the actual code for the getter and setter?

Tried in nuxt.config.js directly, but doesn't work.

Thanks.